# Assigning plot to a variable in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create 2 line plots.

But I noticed that using a `for` loop will generate two plots with `y=mev2` (instead of a plot based on `y=mev1` and another one based on `y=mev2`).

The code below shows the observation here.

```
mev1 <- c(1,3,7)
mev2 <- c(9,8,2)
Period <- c(1960, 1970, 1980)
df <- data.frame(Period, mev1, mev2)

library(ggplot2)
# Method 1: Creating plot1 and plot2 without using "for" loop (hard-code)
plot1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Period, y=unlist(as.list(df[2])))) + geom_line()
plot2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Period, y=unlist(as.list(df[3])))) + geom_line()

# Method 2: Creating plot1 and plot2 using "for" loop
for (i in 1:2) {
   y_var <- unlist(as.list(df[i+1]))
   assign(paste("plot", i, sep = ""), ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Period, y=y_var)) + geom_line())
}
```

Seems like this is due to some `ggplot()`'s way of working that I am not aware of.

Question:

- If I want to use Method 2, how should I modify the logic?
- People said that using `assign()` is not an "R-style", so I wonder what's an alternate way to do this? Say, using `list`?

Comment: The way to do it - transform wide to long and plot `ggplot(reshape2::melt(df, "Period"), aes(Period, value, color = variable)) + geom_line()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible answer with no `tidyverse` command added is :

```
library(ggplot2)

y_var <- colnames(df)
for (i in 1:2) {
  assign(paste("plot", i, sep = ""),
         ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x=y_var[1], y=y_var[1 + i])) +
           geom_line())
}

plot1
plot2
```

You may use `aes_string`. I hope it helps.

**EDIT 1**

If you want to stock your plot in a list, you can use this :

Initialize your list :

```
n <- 2 # number of plots
list_plot <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
names(list_plot) <- paste("plot", 1:n)
```

Fill it :

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  list_plot[[i]] <- ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x=y_var[1], y=y_var[1 + i])) +
           geom_line()
}
```

Display :

```
list_plot[[1]]
list_plot[[2]]
```

Comment: It seems you're using functions from external packages, it should be better put those packages in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For lines in different "plots", you can simplify it with `facet_wrap()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
gather(variable, value, -c(Period)) %>% # wide to long format
ggplot(aes(Period, value)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(vars(variable))
```

[image]

You can also put it in a loop if necessary and store the results in a list:

```
# empty list
listed <- list()
# fill the list with the plots
for (i in c(2:3)){
     listed[[i-1]] <- df[,-i]  %>%
                      gather(variable, value, -c(Period)) %>% 
                      ggplot(aes(Period, value)) + geom_line()
                 }

# to get the plots
listed[[1]]
listed[[2]]
```

Comment: In your loop approach your y axis label is just "value" instead of "mev1" and "mev2". And the list elements are not named. For this reason I would go with Rémi Coulauds approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want 2 separate plots? `ggplot`s way to do this would be to get data in long format and then plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Period) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Period, value, color = name) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using a **function** and **lapply**. I recognize that you asked how to solve this using a loop. Still, I think it might be useful to consider this approach.

```
library(ggplot2)
mev1 <- c(1,3,7)
mev2 <- c(9,8,2)
Period <- c(1960, 1970, 1980)
df <- data.frame(Period, mev1, mev2)

myplot <- function(yvar){
  plot <- ggplot(df, aes(Period, !!sym(yvar))) + geom_line()
  return(plot)
}

colnames <- c("mev1","mev2")
list <- lapply(colnames, myplot)
names(list) <- paste0("plot_", colnames)
# Alternativing naming: names(list) <- paste0("plot", 1:2)
```

Using this approach you can easily apply your plot function to whatever columns you like. You can **specify the columns by name**, which may be preferrabe to specifying by position. Plots are saved in a list, and they are named afterwards using the `names` attribute. In my example I named the plots `plot_mev1` and `plot_mev2`. But you can easily adjust to some other naming. E.g. write `names(list) <- paste0("plot", 1:2)` to get `plot1` and `plot2`.

Note that I used `!!sym()` in the ggplot call. This is essentally an alternative to `aes_string` which was used in the answer of Rémi Coulaud. In this way ggplot understands even in the context of a function or in the context of a loop that "mev1" is a column of your dataset and not just a text string